# Removing physical volumes from a mounted logical volume

Tags: storage, lvm

I have a virtual machine with two disks, `sda1` and `sda2`. I have a volume group (`vg_linux`) with these two physical volumes and I want to remove `sda2` from this volume group. However, on this volume group, there is the root `/` logical volume, which is obviously mounted so I can't use `vgreduce vg_linux /dev/sda2`.

I can't add more disks or change the storage system in any way.

Does somebody have an idea of a way to remove `sda2` from `vg_linux` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the free space in `vg_linux` exceeds the size of `sda2`. Then move the physical volume off to other PVs, and remove it.

```
pvmove /dev/sda2
vgreduce vg_linux /dev/sda2
pvremove /dev/sda2
```

---

Multiple partitions of the same disk in the same VG does not make much sense to me, there is no performance or administrative advantage. I prefer to create VGs on entire disks and skip the partition table:  `vgcreate vgdata /dev/sdb /dev/sdc`.